# How to copy a URL in Lynx without using the mouse

Tags: url, copy, clipboard, lynx

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I want to copy a URL in Lynx without using the mouse. The URL should be copied to the clipboard. I have tried using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, but it does not get copied to the clipboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I copy a link in Lynx?](http://superuser.com/questions/82969/how-do-i-copy-a-link-in-lynx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well if you don't mind complicated stuff, you can do this if you open lynx inside a screen, do:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Escape</kbd>,
- arrows to get to the start of the url
- <kbd>enter</kbd> to start selection
- arrows to get to the end of the url
- <kbd>enter</kbd> to end selection and push it into screen's buffer
- paste it into a shell using <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>
- and do `echo "that paste" | xclip -selection clipboard`

maybe using `w3m` or `lynx` you can pipe a selection of text into `xclip`, but that's far from being sure.

Comment: though, in the end, as you're using Xorg, for copy/pasting, use the mouse, it's easier :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. Just what I wanted